# file path to find folder where files deleted from recycle bin are sitting

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Unfortunately my business has to close, which leaves me to sell a number of laptops off.

I want to ensure any ex customer information cant be recovered after being deleted from the recycle bin by the new owner. I have an effective file shredder programme, which will do this, but it relies on you adding the file or folder you wish to shred.

So can anyone kindly help by telling me the file path to find the folder on Windows 7 please.

I am looking for just a clear answer such as for example---

C/windows/user/system/user/recycle/deleted files  etc ( this is just a made up example)

I found the answer once, which worked great, but lost it.

Ever since I can only find answers to similar questions which just talk about files "are not really deleted from the recycle bin but are still in the computer" etc and never answer the question being asked.

(Also I don't want to format the drives )

So hope someone will tell me how to find the folder for deleted files on Windows 7 to load into the file shredder programme,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When files are deleted from the recycle bin, they are simply flagged as deleted, and the contents are left right where they were. (The same is true if you bypass the recycle bin and delete the file directly). A file recovery program can recover some of these files, if the space they were written to hasn't been reused by another file yet. A good file shredding program should also be able to clear all empty portions of the disk, which would destroy the file contents.

If you wear a tin-foil hat, it's possible for governments to retrieve the data at that point, but not without enormous cost and effort. Most experts recommend multiple random-data writes and complete drive destruction (shredding, actually) for government-level sensitive data, but that's probably way overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use CCleaner (for example). It has option to wipe free space only. This will work, because as Jamas said, files remain there, where it ware. Cleaning "free" space will wipe deleted files for good.